# Regex: Select everything between the first pair of underscores

Tags: regex

This is my list

```
record_BANGLADESH_data_1565_803.txt
record_BHUTAN_data_1565_251.txt
record_BRUNEI_data_1565_818.txt
record_CAMBODIA_data_1565_727.txt
record_CHINA PART 1_data_1565_691.txt
record_CHINA PART 2_data_1565_410.txt
```

I would like to extract everything between the first pair of underscores, so I end up with this:

```
BANGLADESH
BHUTAN
BRUNEI
CAMBODIA
CHINA PART 1
CHINA PART 2
```

I think a look ahead command would help.

This is what I have so far:

```
(?<=_)[^A-Z]+(?=_)
```

However, it ends up with this:

```
record_BANGLADESH_803
record_BHUTAN_251
record_BRUNEI_818
record_CAMBODIA_727
record_CHINA PART 1_691
record_CHINA PART 2_410
How can I fix it?
```

Here is a [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/G7FtkQ/8) with my code

Comment: Use a capturing group `^[^_]+_([^_]+)_` https://regex101.com/r/OzxgGg/1 with an achor `^`

Comment: What programming language or tool are you using? [`\K`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html) is supported in PCRE and non-fixed width Lookbehinds are supported in .NET regex. Otherwise, your best bet would be a capturing group as Thefourthbird suggested.

Comment: @Thefourthbird That works on Regex101, but when I try it in an app that has Regex built in (such as [Name Changer[(https://mrrsoftware.com/namechanger/)). It does the opposite of what I want, it removes the country names, but leaves all the text outside the underscores. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: The values you want to extract are in capturing group 1. What is you expected result? Are you replacing all except the country names? Perhaps it works the other way around, removing the groups and keep the rest `^([^_]+_)[^_]+(_.*)$` https://regex101.com/r/lwXCig/1

Comment: @The fourth bird, Thanks for your help. The expected result is to remove everything but the country names (e.g. so only the country names are left). When I use `^([^_]+_)[^_]+(_.*)$` in [Name Changer](http://mrrsoftware.com/namechanger), it removes everything (even the country names).

Comment: Can you match this this pattern `^[^_]+_([^_]+)_.*$` and use for example `$1` or `\1` as the replacement? https://regex101.com/r/tBgOwR/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird That works, please post as answer and I will mark correct.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the string contains at least two underscores? If not, what is to be returned if it contains zero or one underscores?

Comment: `_([^_]+)_` is enough for those functions that return the first match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match the whole string and make use of a negated character class `[^_]+`

```
^[^_]+_([^_]+)_.*$
```

In parts

- `^` Start of string
- `[^_]+_` Match 1+ times any char except `_`, then match the first _
- `(` Capture group 1

  - `[^_]+` Match 1+ times any char except `_`
- `)` Close group 1
- `_.*` Match the second underscore followed by any char 0+ times
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tBgOwR/1)

You could add `\r\n` the the character class `[^_]` to prevent matching newlines.

In the replacement use the first capturing group `$1`